# RegEx to grab all values in quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have this regular expression which does wonders for me:

```
~--?(?<key>[^= ]+)[ =]
    (?|
        "(?<value> [^\\\\"]*+ (?s:\\\\.[^\\\\"]*)*+ )"
      |
        ([^ ?"]*)
    )~x
```

It allows me to create a PHP key-value / associative array from a string input like this:

```
-Parameter1=1234 -Parameter2=38518 -param3 "Test \"escaped\"" -param4 10 -param5 0 -param6 "TT" -param7 "Seven" -param8 "secret" "-SuperParam9=4857?--SuperParam10=123"
```

Now, the only problem is that [I've got it as an answer for my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48527221/parsing-parameters-from-command-line-with-regex-and-php) and I am clueless how to update the regex expression to fit my **new needs**. RegEx is not my strongest side.

New pattern I'd like to introduce in that expression is (and to keep existing functionality as well):

```
-parameterX"Value like this, glue is nothing" -paramY"Yes, like this" -paramZ"120983"
```

I have tried a stupid hack like, intercepting my input string and replacing all quotes with a whitespace added on it's left side, like this:

```
$input = str_replace('"', ' "', $input);
```

But this is not what would anyone want...

Comment: In your original regex value for `param3` is empty. Is that right?

Comment: No. `param3` value is `Test "escaped"`. Glue can be: `=`, ` ` (whitespace) and `` (nothing). I know, it's wierd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must make sure the key part does not match  a double quote, and that `[ =]` part is optional (since in the new format, there are not spaces  between the key and the `"..."` part.

Use

```
/--?(?<key>[^= "]+)[ =]?
(?|
    "(?<value> [^\\"]*+ (?s:\\.[^\\"]*)*+ )"
  |
    ([^ ?"]*)
)/x
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/chQvG7/1).

The  modified part is `(?<key>[^= "]+)[ =]?`: `[^= "]+` matches one or more chars other than `=`, space and `"` (maybe, `\w+` will be enough) and `[ =]?` matches one or zero occurrences of `=` or a space.